# How to Start Echo nest Server?

Tags: python, apache, solr, tokyo-tyrant, echonest

i'm trying to install echo nest server,according to [github instruction](https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-server) 
first, i install java,python,all of python component that is requirement and finally install apache solar from bitnami on windows 10.

but i've problem about how to install Tokyo Tyrant ?! and finally when i run this command(for start echonest server):

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/path/to/echoprint-server/solr/solr/solr/ -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar start.jar
```

apache solar has exception:java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource solarconfig.xml in classpath

but solar config file is exist in directory

> C:\echoprint-server\solr\solr\solr\conf\solrconfig.xml

and reply for me at the end

> Started SelectChannelConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8502

How Can i fix it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was with this problem and resolved using the complete path to the Solr home with a final slash, too.

Solr was trying to concatenate the path with the ~ with the current directory, so it wasn`t founding the config file.

I was using:

```
~/Desktop/www/echoprint/solr/solr/solr/
```

And when i changed to this, it started working.

```
/home/melhergui/Desktop/www/echoprint/solr/solr/solr/
```

If you are already doing like this, i think you could escape your path and try to see in the Solr log that prints in the screen. This was where i found the problem:

```
INFO: using system property solr.solr.home: ~/Desktop/www/echoprint/solr/solr/
Dec 27, 2015 11:54:28 AM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer initialize
INFO: looking for solr.xml: /home/melhergui/Desktop/www/echoprint/solr/solr/~/Desktop/www/echoprint/solr/solr/solr.xml
...
SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '~/Desktop/www/echoprint/solr/solr/conf/', cwd=/home/melhergui/Desktop/www/echoprint/solr/solr
```

I hope it helps you to make it run.